# ServiceStack 3.9.43 JsonSerializer: IncludeNull has no effect on serialization?

Tags: servicestack, jsonserializer

In the AppHost

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;

    SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
    {
        ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api",
        DefaultContentType = ServiceStack.Common.Web.ContentType.Json,
        DefaultJsonpCacheExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0),
        GlobalResponseHeaders = { { "Cache-Control", "no-cache" } },
    });
...
```

When I do Dto.ToJson(), null fields are not serialized at all. Found this as my service was throwing serialization error.

Comment: In all serialization errors please always add the DTO you're trying to serialized and the full HTTP output - We always need this to see what the issue is.